# Java Socket Multithread File Transfer getting stuck after upload

Tags: java, multithreading, file, swing, sockets

I've had implemented a server-client program using Java Socket and multithreading. The programm allow the clients to send files to server, list files and download that files. But I'm having an issue, when my client upload a file the programm/gui get stuck and the client can't do none of the operations. Can't lis, download or upload. But the file is sendend correctly to the server. Anyone know what's happening??

My Client

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileClient {
    private static final String SERVER_HOST = "localhost";
    private static final int SERVER_PORT = 12345;

    private static Socket socket;
    private static DataInputStream in;
    private static DataOutputStream out;

    private static JList<String> fileList;
    private static DefaultListModel<String> listModel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT);
            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("File Client");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(400, 400);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            JButton listButton = new JButton("List Files");
            JButton downloadButton = new JButton("Download File");
            JButton uploadButton = new JButton("Upload File");

            listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
            fileList = new JList<>(listModel);
            fileList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(fileList);

            listButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // Execute a operação de listagem em uma thread separada
                    SwingWorker<Void, Void> listWorker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                            listFiles();
                            return null;
                        }
                    };
                    listWorker.execute();
                }
            });

            downloadButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // Execute a operação de download em uma thread separada
                    SwingWorker<Void, Void> downloadWorker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                            downloadFile();
                            return null;
                        }
                    };
                    downloadWorker.execute();
                }
            });

            uploadButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // Execute a operação de upload em uma thread separada
                    SwingWorker<Void, Void> uploadWorker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                            uploadFile();
                            return null;
                        }
                    };
                    uploadWorker.execute();
                }
            });

            panel.add(listButton);
            panel.add(downloadButton);
            panel.add(uploadButton);

            frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void listFiles() {
        try {
            out.writeUTF("list");
            int numFiles = in.readInt();
            List<String> files = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < numFiles; i++) {
                String fileName = in.readUTF();
                files.add(fileName);
            }
            listModel.clear();
            for (String file : files) {
                listModel.addElement(file);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void downloadFile() {
        String selectedFile = fileList.getSelectedValue();
        if (selectedFile != null) {
            try {
                out.writeUTF("download");
                out.writeUTF(selectedFile);

                String response = in.readUTF();
                if (response.equals("exists")) {
                    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                    fileChooser.setSelectedFile(new File(selectedFile));
                    int returnVal = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);

                    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                        File savedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                        try (OutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(savedFile)) {
                            long fileSize = in.readLong();
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                            int bytesRead;
                            long totalBytesRead = 0;
                            while (totalBytesRead < fileSize) {
                                bytesRead = in.read(buffer, 0, (int) Math.min(1024, fileSize - totalBytesRead));
                                if (bytesRead == -1) {
                                    break;
                                }
                                fileOut.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                            }
                        }
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File downloaded successfully.");
                    }
                } else if (response.equals("not_found")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File not found on the server.");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void uploadFile() {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            try {
                out.writeUTF("upload");
                out.writeUTF(selectedFile.getName());

                try (BufferedInputStream fileIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(selectedFile))) {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = fileIn.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }
                // Indique o término do envio de arquivo
                out.writeLong(-1); // -1 para indicar o fim do arquivo
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File uploaded successfully.");

                // Após o upload bem-sucedido, atualize a lista de arquivos
                listFiles();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

My Server:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class FileServer {
    private static final int PORT = 12345;
    private static final String FILE_DIRECTORY = "C:\\Users\\carlosdaniel\\Desktop\\Code\\Facul\\Redes\\FileTransfer\\Server\\src\\arquivos_servidor\\";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT)) {
            System.out.println("Server is running and listening on port " + PORT);
            while (true) {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                Runnable clientHandler = new ClientHandler(clientSocket);
                executorService.submit(clientHandler);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
        private Socket clientSocket;

        public ClientHandler(Socket clientSocket) {
            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try (DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream())) {
                while (true) {
                    String command = in.readUTF();
                    if (command.equals("list")) {
                        File dir = new File(FILE_DIRECTORY);
                        String[] files = dir.list();
                        out.writeInt(files.length);
                        for (String fileName : files) {
                            out.writeUTF(fileName);
                        }
                    } else if (command.equals("download")) {
                        String fileName = in.readUTF();
                        File file = new File(FILE_DIRECTORY + fileName);
                        if (file.exists()) {
                            out.writeUTF("exists");
                            try (InputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file)) {
                                long fileSize = file.length();
                                out.writeLong(fileSize);
                                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                                int bytesRead;
                                while ((bytesRead = fileIn.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                    out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            out.writeUTF("not_found");
                        }
                    } else if (command.equals("upload")) {
                        String fileName = in.readUTF();
                        try (OutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(FILE_DIRECTORY + fileName)) {
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                            int bytesRead;
                            while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                fileOut.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my File Model:

```
public class MyFile {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private byte[] data;
    private String fileExtension;

    public MyFile(int id, String name, byte[] data, String fileExtension) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.data = data;
        this.fileExtension = fileExtension;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setData(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setFileExtension(String fileExtension) {
        this.fileExtension = fileExtension;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public String getFileExtension() {
        return fileExtension;
    }
}
```

Comment: While you're making use of `SwingWorker`, you're still violating the threading rules of the Swing API.  Swing is NOT thread safe, you should not be modifying the UI or any state the UI relies on, from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  You should be making use of the `SwingWorker`'s API support to either `publish`/`process` information of the running thread or returning a value from the `SwingWorker` which can be later retrieved, possibly through the use of a `PropertyChangeListener` and monitoring for the `DONE` state of the `SwingWorker`

Comment: As a example, your `listFiles` workflow shouldn't modifying the `listModel`.  This is a candidate for the `publish`/`process` workflow.  Your download and upload workflows should not be presenting file dialogs, these should be done either before or after the tasks have completed (ie download the file to a temp location and then prompt to the user where they'd like to save it - or prompt before hand)

Comment: Personally, I would encapsulate the socket handling on the client its own class, but that's me

Comment: The issue is, `DataInputStream#read` will never return `-1`, writing `-1` from the client will just result in the server receiving the value via the buffer - I would consider changing your approach slightly and instead first send the file size (in bytes) and then have the loop exit once it's successfully read that number of bytes, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047793/java-socket-file-transfer-files-dont-transfer-completely)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your primary issue is here...

```
} else if (command.equals("upload")) {
    String fileName = in.readUTF();
    try (OutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(FILE_DIRECTORY + fileName)) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fileOut.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
}
```

Specifically, `while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {`.  Unless you're going to close the stream at the other end, it's not possible to have `read` return `-1` - and writing `-1` at the other end just means that the server will return `-1` into the buffer.

While there are a number of possible solutions, simplest is probably to send the file size as well and then ONLY read that number of bytes, for example...

```
} else if (command.equals("upload")) {
    String fileName = in.readUTF();
    long totalBytes = in.readLong();
    try (OutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(FILE_DIRECTORY + "/" + fileName)) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        long totalBytesRead = 0;
        while (totalBytesRead < totalBytes) {
            int bytesRead = in.read(buffer, 0, (int)Math.min(1024, totalBytes - totalBytesRead));
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
            fileOut.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
}
```

This `int bytesRead = in.read(buffer, 0, (int)Math.min(1024, totalBytes - totalBytesRead));` is really important.  You don't want to read any more bytes then you're expecting, otherwise you will consume more data, like the next command.

## All the "other" issues

Swing is not thread safe, this means that you shouldn't be updating the UI or any state the UI relies on from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

While testing your code, I run into a number of issue when listing the files because, while you execute the request in a `SwingWorker`, you continue to update the `ListModel` from the same background thread.

Instead, you should be making use of the `publish`/`process` support to sync updates back to the EDT.

The following is a reimplementation focusing on fixing the threading issues.  It makes use delegation, observer pattern and single responsibility concepts, as such it makes use of the `Action` API and attempts to decouple the `SwingWorker` workflow into stand alone concepts.

It also encapsulates much of the client socket workflow into a self contained workflow, further decoupling the code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class FileClient extends JPanel {
    private static final String SERVER_HOST = "localhost";
    private static final int SERVER_PORT = 12345;

    private ClientSocketManager socketManager;

    private JList<String> fileList;
    private DefaultListModel<String> listModel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket(SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT);
            ClientSocketManager socketManager = new ClientSocketManager(socket);
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("File Client");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.add(new FileClient(socketManager));
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public FileClient(ClientSocketManager socketManager) {
        this.socketManager = socketManager;
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
        fileList = new JList<>(listModel);
        fileList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(fileList);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton listButton = new JButton(new ListFilesAction(socketManager, listModel));
        JButton downloadButton = new JButton("Download File");
        JButton uploadButton = new JButton(new UploadFileAction(socketManager, listModel));

        panel.add(listButton);
        panel.add(downloadButton);
        panel.add(uploadButton);

        add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    protected class ListFilesAction extends AbstractAction {
        private DefaultListModel<String> listModel;
        private ClientSocketManager socketManager;

        public ListFilesAction(ClientSocketManager socketManager, DefaultListModel<String> listModel) {
            putValue(NAME, "List Files");
            this.listModel = listModel;
            this.socketManager = socketManager;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ListFilesWorker worker = new ListFilesWorker(socketManager, listModel);
            worker.addObserver(new AbstractObservableSwingWorker.DefaultObserver<>() {
                @Override
                public void didStart(AbstractObservableSwingWorker<Void, String> source) {
                    listModel.clear();
                    setEnabled(false);
                }

                @Override
                public void didComplete(AbstractObservableSwingWorker<Void, String> source) {
                    setEnabled(true);
                    try {
                        source.get();
                    } catch (Exception exp) {
                        exp.printStackTrace();
                        if (!(e.getSource() instanceof Component)) {
                            return;
                        }
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) e.getSource(), "Failed to list files from server due to an error", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            });
            worker.execute();
        }
    }

    protected class UploadFileAction extends AbstractAction {
        private ClientSocketManager socketManager;
        private DefaultListModel<String> listModel;

        public UploadFileAction(ClientSocketManager socketManager, DefaultListModel<String> listModel) {
            putValue(NAME, "Upload File");
            this.socketManager = socketManager;
            this.listModel = listModel;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            Component parent = null;
            if (e.getSource() instanceof Component) {
                parent = (Component) e.getSource();
            }

            if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(parent) == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
                return;
            }
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            if (selectedFile == null) {
                return;
            }
            UploadFileWorker worker = new UploadFileWorker(socketManager, selectedFile, listModel);
            worker.addObserver(new AbstractObservableSwingWorker.DefaultObserver<Void, String>() {
                @Override
                public void didStart(AbstractObservableSwingWorker<Void, String> source) {
                    setEnabled(false);
                }

                @Override
                public void didComplete(AbstractObservableSwingWorker<Void, String> source) {
                    setEnabled(true);
                    Component parent = null;
                    if (e.getSource() instanceof Component) {
                        parent = (Component) e.getSource();
                    }
                    try {
                        source.get();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, "File uploaded successfully", "Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    } catch (Exception exp) {
                        exp.printStackTrace();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, "File uploaded failed", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            });
            worker.execute();
        }
    }

    protected class ListFilesWorker extends AbstractObservableSwingWorker<Void, String> {
        private ClientSocketManager socketManager;
        private DefaultListModel<String> listModel;

        public ListFilesWorker(ClientSocketManager socketManager, DefaultListModel<String> listModel) {
            this.socketManager = socketManager;
            this.listModel = listModel;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            socketManager.listFiles(new ClientSocketManager.FileListObserver() {
                @Override
                public void didRecieveFileName(String name) {
                    publish(name);
                }
            });
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
            listModel.addAll(chunks);
        }

        public ClientSocketManager getSocketManager() {
            return socketManager;
        }

        public DefaultListModel<String> getListModel() {
            return listModel;
        }
    }

    protected class UploadFileWorker extends ListFilesWorker {
        private File file;

        public UploadFileWorker(ClientSocketManager socketManager, File file, DefaultListModel<String> listModel) {
            super(socketManager, listModel);
            this.file = file;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            getSocketManager().uploadFile(file);
            return super.doInBackground();
        }
    }

    public abstract class AbstractObservableSwingWorker<T, V> extends SwingWorker<T, V> {
        public interface Observer<T, V> {
            public void didStart(AbstractObservableSwingWorker<T, V> source);

            public void didComplete(AbstractObservableSwingWorker<T, V> source);

            public void progressDidChange(AbstractObservableSwingWorker<T, V> source, int progress);
        }

        public static class DefaultObserver<T, V> implements Observer<T, V> {
            @Override
            public void didStart(AbstractObservableSwingWorker<T, V> source) {
            }

            @Override
            public void didComplete(AbstractObservableSwingWorker<T, V> source) {
            }

            @Override
            public void progressDidChange(AbstractObservableSwingWorker<T, V> source, int progress) {
            }
        }

        private List<Observer<T, V>> listeners;

        public AbstractObservableSwingWorker() {
            this.listeners = new ArrayList<>();

            addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                    Object value = evt.getNewValue();
                    String propertyName = evt.getPropertyName();
                    if ("state".equals(propertyName) && value instanceof SwingWorker.StateValue) {
                        SwingWorker.StateValue state = (SwingWorker.StateValue) value;
                        if (state == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
                            fireDidComplete();
                        } else if (state == SwingWorker.StateValue.STARTED) {
                            fireDidStart();
                        }
                    } else if ("progress".equals(propertyName) && value instanceof Integer) {
                        int progress = (int) value;
                        fireProgressDidChange(progress);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public void addObserver(Observer<T, V> observer) {
            listeners.add(observer);
        }

        public void removeObserver(Observer<T, V> observer) {
            listeners.add(observer);
        }

        protected void fireDidComplete() {
            if (listeners.isEmpty()) {
                return;
            }
            for (Observer observer : listeners) {
                observer.didComplete(this);
            }
        }

        protected void fireDidStart() {
            if (listeners.isEmpty()) {
                return;
            }
            for (Observer observer : listeners) {
                observer.didStart(this);
            }
        }

        protected void fireProgressDidChange(int progress) {
            if (listeners.isEmpty()) {
                return;
            }
            for (Observer observer : listeners) {
                observer.progressDidChange(this, progress);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### `ClientSocketManager`

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ClientSocketManager implements Closeable {
private Socket socket;
private DataInputStream dis;
private DataOutputStream dos;

```
public interface FileListObserver {
    public void didRecieveFileName(String name);
}

public ClientSocketManager(Socket socket) throws IOException {
    this.socket = socket;
    dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
}

@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    try {
        dis.close();
    } catch (IOException exp) {
    }
    try {
        dos.close();
    } catch (IOException exp) {
    }
    socket.close();
}

public List<String> listFiles(FileListObserver observer) throws IOException {
    dos.writeUTF("list");
    int numFiles = dis.readInt();
    List<String> files = new ArrayList<>(numFiles);
    for (int i = 0; i < numFiles; i++) {
        String fileName = dis.readUTF();
        files.add(fileName);
        if (observer != null) {
            observer.didRecieveFileName(fileName);
        }
    }
    return files;
}

public void uploadFile(File file) throws IOException {
    dos.writeUTF("upload");
    dos.writeUTF(file.getName());
    dos.writeLong(file.length());

    try (BufferedInputStream fileIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = fileIn.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
    dos.flush();
}
```

}

Have a look at [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) and [How to Use Actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for some more details